# Understanding C++ constexpr Performance

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, raytracing

I recently wrote a compile-time ray tracer using `constexpr` functions with C++17. The full source code can be seen [here](https://github.com/marovira/ctrt). The relevant code for this question looks like this:

```
constexpr auto image = []() {
        StaticImage<image_width, image_height> image;

        Camera camera{Pointf{0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f},
                      Vectorf{0.0f},
                      Vectorf{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
                      500.0f};

        std::array<Shapes, 1> shapes_list{Sphere{Pointf{0.0f}, 150.0f}};
        std::array<Materials, 1> materials_list{DefaultMaterial{}};
        ShapeContainer<decltype(shapes_list)> shapes{std::move(shapes_list)};
        MaterialContainer<decltype(materials_list)> materials{
            std::move(materials_list)};

        SphereScene scene;
        scene.set_camera(camera);

        Renderer::render(scene, image, shapes, materials);
        return image;
    }();
```

Where each of the classes shown here (`StaticImage`, `Camera`, `Shapes`, `Materials`, `ShapeContainer`, `MaterialContainer`, and `SphereScene`) consist entirely of `constexpr` functions. `Renderer::render` is also `constexpr` and is in charge of looping over every pixel in the image, shooting rays into the scene, and setting the corresponding colour.

With this current setup and an image of 512x512, using MSVC 16.9.2 in Release mode, the compiler takes approximately 35 minutes to finish generating the image. During this process, its memory usage rises to the point where it ends up using almost 64GB of RAM.

So, my questions is: why are the compilation time and memory usage so high?

My theory was that part of the reason for the compilation time was the complexity of the call-stacks (i.e. lots of templates, CRTP, and depth), so I tried simplifying the call stack a bit by removing several templates (the `Vector` class is no longer templated for example) and managed to reduce the compilation time down to 32 minutes, and the memory usage to 61GB. Better, but still very high. The thing is that I can't quite figure out why it's so slow. I do understand that evaluating all of the `constexpr` functions is a very involved process (since the compiler has to check for UB, type-deduction, etc.) but I wasn't expecting it to be quite this slow. I'm also really confused by the high memory usage. The image array itself uses no more than 4MB of memory (`512 * 512 * 3 * sizeof(float)`) so where is the extra memory coming from?

Comment: Your question is about a specific compiler. You should add the tag for the compiler you are asking about.

Comment: Am I right that you're passing image itself (pixels values) as template argument inside `MaterialContainer<decltype(materials_list)>`? If so then you shouldn't do that, because template arguments should be very tiny, this is might be the cause of problem. If you want to pass data around then starting from probably C++20 or even C++17 you can create structures and pass values of structures as arguments of functions. This structures can be constexpr too. For example `std::array<>` can be easily used inside constexpr function. But definitely you should pass data around as function arguments.

Comment: @Arty  Agree. It may be memoizing all the templated instantiations.

Comment: You're turning the compiler into a graphical processor and expect it to be performant? I think you're abusing the compiler. Anyways, the reason, I suspect, has to do with the vast amount of template instantiates.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm using MSVC as an example, since it is the only compiler I have access to for this, but the question itself is more general.

Comment: The amount of works compiler has to do to support constexpr template metaprogramming is astounding. I am not surprised with your resource usage.

Comment: @Arty no. The `MaterialContainer` doesn't receive the image itself, nor is the image data passed as a template argument. `Renderer::render` is templated on the type of the image, but the data itself is never passed in as a template argument, always as a function argument.

Comment: @MariusBancila not performant in the strict sense of the word. I'm mostly surprised by how slow it is and trying to understand why it is this way. I never expected it to be faster than a runtime ray tracer, but I also wasn't expecting it to take half an hour!

Comment: You're using the compiler like a C++ interpreter. It doesn't JIT the code so the speed difference from compiled native code will be vast.

Comment: @Arty what do you mean by template argument should be tiny ?

Comment: What profiling have you done?  Yes, profiling; the easiest of which is to vary some parameters and record fresh build times for each.  Is it O(# of pixels) or not?  Is it O(# of materials)?  As a guess, your extra memory comes from memoization.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont So the compile time + memory usage increases with the number of pixels in the image, so it is at least `O(n * n)`. The number of materials doesn't seem to have that big of an impact (though I suspect the number of shapes will, haven't tried it yet).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Just to make sure that I understand your guess, does this mean that every time the parsing goes through a function it copies the entire image array? So for example if at some point the call stack is 4 levels deep and the image is 3MB, it will use 12MB at the bottom of the stack?

Comment: @mauricio seems likely; if everything gets memoized, which breaks your code.  I guess 90% of your code doesn't need the entire image?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's interesting, and does explain why it uses so much memory. You're right, the only function that uses the image is `Renderer::render`. All other classes just deal with vectors and rays. Though I wonder why, since none of the other functions even receive the image as a parameter (template, function, or otherwise).

Comment: @mauicio Is it stored in the class?  The object is an implicit parameter to every method...  Write purer code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230564/discussion-between-mauricio-and-yakk-adam-nevraumont).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile-time execution is going to be *much* less efficient than runtime execution. The compiler has to do more work to execute the same code. The point of compile-time execution is to do computations that you can't do at runtime. And sometimes, to compile-time cache simpler computations.

Writing a whole, non-trivial application that exists only at compile-time is not going to be a fast thing to get done.

As for the particulars, the principle reason for the cost increase is that compile-time execution has to detect *all* undefined behavior. This means that a lot of things that might just be offsetting a pointer have to be more complicated. Stack variables can't just be offsetting the stack pointer; they have to track the lifetime of the object explicitly. And so forth.

Compile-time execution is basically interpreted C++. And there's not much reason to make it a particularly fast interpreter. Most compile-time operations are dealing with computations based on types and simple values, not with complex data structures. So that's what compilers are primarily optimized for.

I recall that some noise had been made recently to improve Clang's `constexpr` execution via better interpretation. But I don't know how much came of it.

Comment: True, and I am aware of the fact that it would be much slower, but I wasn't expecting it to be that much slower. That said, I hadn't considered the cost of pointer offsets into arrays and the like. Does this have anything to do with the memory usage as well?